# My .php pages have, unwanted, 301 errors according to google webmaster tools

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http, http-status-code-301

I recently used google webmaster tools to do a fetch as google. The result for all my pages that have a php extension cam back something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 12:23:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.hla.co.za/studio/
Content-Length: 236
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.hla.co.za/studio/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

I have not done anything to create this 301 redirect and my .htaccess page is blank.
How can I fix this error?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the original URL of site that you're accessing?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't anything in any htaccess files?